# PhpStorm isn't reanalyze all current page

Tags: ide, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

How can I reanalyse current page; because when I paste some code, PhpStorm(Version 2021.2) doesn't reanalyse to the all page.

Is there a shortcut for this process?

[image: PhpStorm show an error]

I'm selecting to all page then cutting then paste again and the problem disappears. Like this :

[image: Problem is gone]

Comment: What is your PhpStorm version **exactly**?

Comment: PhpStorm 2021.2

Comment: Please install **latest 2021.2.1** and check there. Invalidate Caches if needed. The issue that affects mainly Turkish users should be fixed there. If still the same -- let me know.

Comment: I can already solve the problem by cutting and pasting. The way which you show is correct, but it is a very long process. I'm looking to see if there is a short operation. Like the F5 operation.

Comment: I hope I could explain.

Comment: I understand your issue. It is supposed to be fixed in 2021.2.1 build. Have you installed it? *"The way which you show is correct, but it is a very long process."* So installing a newer version is unwanted and very long process? WTF? Please explain.

Comment: I installed https://prnt.sc/1r1l1it same problem

Comment: Selecting and cutting this part: https://prnt.sc/1r1lcy2
Paste again: https://prnt.sc/1r1lemx

Problem is gone.

Comment: This is not a useful way. The way you show is a long process for a single line of code.

Comment: 1) *"This is not a useful way."* Which "not useful way"? What you are talking about? You need to be more clear. Sorry, but I do not understand you here. 2) *"I installed https://prnt.sc/1r1l1it same problem"* Disable **Grazie** plugin and restart the IDE -- any better now?

Comment: If you write code from scratch, you don't have these problems. But if you delete an existing variable above and put it back, PhpStorm doesn't know that the variable exists. So are its objects. It's probably the same with everything it has to relate to.

After removing the Grazie plugin, the problem was resolved.

Tried the installation in different ways.

After the error after the update, I reinstalled from scratch. But the problem has not changed.

I hope problem resolve in versiyon 2.1.2.

I'll share my experiance.

Thanks for all @LazyOne

Comment: *"After removing the Grazie plugin, the problem was resolved. "* Because the issue is in the Grazie plugin -- it somehow affects inspections as well. Quite likely it's this one: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-275168. If it's not in 2021.2.1 already then shoudl be in next 2021.2.2 then